# Java Properties file Replace retrieved String

Tags: java, properties-file

I am reading a text from property file and the text is `your deals ends on $enddate`. Now i want to replace the endate to a specific date in my class after retrieving using getProperty method.

String info = props.getProperty("message");

property file contains

**message=your deals ends on $enddate**

Comment: Do you know that `String` class have a methods `replace()` and `replaceAll()`?

Comment: You'd actually better use `MessageFormat`.

Answer (score 3):

In properties file :

```
message=your deals ends on {0}
```

and in Java class :

```
MessageFormat.format((String) props.get("message"), dateToReplace);
```